# How to send FPDF output to GCS bucket from python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am using FPDF python library to create new pdf file. I want my output pdf to be stored on gcs bucket. My code is below:

```
import fpdf

data=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

pdf = fpdf.FPDF(format='letter')
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font("Arial", size=12)

for i in data:
    pdf.write(5,str(i))
    pdf.ln()
pdf.output("gs://bucket_name/output.pdf")
```

its giving No such file or directory: error.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can upload the file from local storage to GCS using the below code example from the [GCS docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-python)

(Look for Code examples > python)

```
from google.cloud import storage


def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
"""Uploads a file to the bucket."""
# bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
# source_file_name = "local/path/to/file"
# destination_blob_name = "storage-object-name"

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)

print(
    "File {} uploaded to {}.".format(
        source_file_name, destination_blob_name
    )
)
```

**Edit**

Cloud Storage supports [streaming](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming#client-libraries) transfers, which allow you to stream data to and from your Cloud Storage account without requiring that the data first be saved to a file.

But per the client libraries > Python note "You cannot currently perform streaming uploads with the Python client library."

Comment: Thanks @Andres S , can't i directly upload file to gcs path instead of saving it on local machine then copy to gcs (bit lengthy and time consuming process)?

Comment: I believe that would be [streaming](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming#client-libraries)  (Cloud Storage supports streaming transfers, which allow you to stream data to and from your Cloud Storage account without requiring that the data first be saved to a file.) - Per the client libraries > Python note "You cannot currently perform streaming uploads with the Python client library."